# Push GstBuffer list to next downstream element

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, gstreamer-0.10

I have a GstBufferList *list inside the upstream element and wanted to pass the same to the downstream element for further processing.

Is there any way in Gstreamer to pass this Gstbufferlist to the next element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gstreamer/gstpad.html?gi-language=c#gst_pad_push_list

`gst_pad_push_list()` pushes `GstBufferList` downstream. If the downstream pad has a `chain_list` implementation it will get the complete list - if not it will call the `chain` function with each `GstBuffer` individually.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The upstream element does not have any chain_list implementation. and I have one doubt how do I will catch this list and downstream side? could you please provide some pseudo-code. new this environment. any valuable input will be great helpful for me.

Comment: Your upstream has the list, right? Just push it downstream via `gst_pad_push_list()`. Your downstream will get the list or single buffers depending whether it can handle a list or not.

Comment: can you please help me on what will be the value of the GstPad argument in the below function.

GstFlowReturn
gst_pad_push_list (GstPad * pad, GstBufferList * list);

Comment: if the downstream element having the below pad configuration.

gst_element_class_add_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_CLASS(klass),

    gst_pad_template_new ("src", GST_PAD_SRC, GST_PAD_ALWAYS, gst_caps_from_string ("{BGR}" ",width = (int) [1, 420], height = (int) [1, 420]")));

Comment: The pad argument would be the `src` pad of the upstream element.

Comment: gst_my_transform_frame_ip (GstVideoFilter * filter, GstVideoFrame * frame) {
GstStaticPadTemplate pad_temp = GST_STATIC_PAD_TEMPLATE ("src", GST_PAD_SRC, GST_PAD_ALWAYS,  gst_caps_from_string (VIDEO_SRC_CAPS));
pad = gst_pad_new_from_static_template (&pad_temp, "src"); // create static pad
GstBufferList *buf_list = gst_buffer_list_new (); // create list
create GstBuffer buf // here  gst_buffer_list_insert(buf_list, idx++, buf); // insert buf.
gst_pad_push_list(pad, buf_list); //  To push the bugger list to downstream element
return GST_FLOW_OK;}

Comment: Hi @Florian above is my implementation code to create the Gstbufeer list and push it to the downstream element. while executing the function  gst_pad_push_list(pad, buf_list); am getting the error "double free or corruption (out) "

Comment: could you help me to find out what wrong I did our here

Comment: I have not made if changes in rx side (downstream element) with respect to gstbuf list. Anything I needs to do here also?

Comment: Hii @Florian, could you please provide your valuable input on the same

Comment: I cant double check/debug your code. But that error sounds like you need to read up upon which functions takes ownership of allocated objects. And who is responsible to release them (and who is not).

Comment: Hii @Florian, Yes It is working fine now. Just wanted your valuable command on the below forum https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044659/adding-inserting-a-gstbuffer-to-the-gstbuffer-pool

Comment: please try to give your valuable feedback on the above forum.

Comment: Hii @Florian, could you please help me to implement the chain list at downstream element?

Comment: Some pseudo code if you can provide that will be appreciated